# Hover over image to produce another image on top without affecting image below using background-image

Tags: html, css, hover, background-image

I want an effect where when a user hovers over a certain book image (see below), a checkmark box will pop up to indicate that it will be selected upon clicking. Eventually, I want a person to be able to press alt (cmd on mac) to select multiple books.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="upload_div">
            <div class="upld_div1">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <div class="book_div"></div>
                        <div class="book_shdw"></div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the current CSS:

```
.book_div {
    background-image:url(../img/book_img.png);
    background-size: 67.9px 105px;
    border:1px solid #bfc1c4;
    width:67.9px;
    height:105px;
    text-align:center;
    margin: auto;
}  

.book_div:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
    background-image: url(../img/book_img.png),
                      url(../img/check.png);
    background-position: relative;  
}
```

I can't for my life figure out how to get another image to go on top of the other upon hover. There are a lot of explanations on SO and other forums on how to get a HTML  to combine with a CSS background-image as well as how to change one image into another, but not many explanations on how to get one on the other. Please also note that the check.png should be placed in the top right corner so that it's outside of the div. Please offer any insight! Thanks.

EDIT:
Thanks for the prompt reply Mathias, that was a little typo. I implemented multiple bg-images in the .book_div:hover css but was still unable. When I do that, the cursor changes upon hover, but the second image does not pop up at all. (I've edited the syntax now and will edit these notes in)
[image: Mockup of Hover CSS]

Comment: Use comma to separate multiple background images. Read about the stacking order here: http://css-tricks.com/stacking-order-of-multiple-backgrounds/

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply Mathias, that was a little typo. I implemented multiple bg-images in the .book_div:hover css but was still unable. When I do that, the cursor changes upon hover, but the second image does not pop up at all. (I've edited the syntax now and will edit these notes in)

Comment: That is why I added the link. The first image goes on top so the check should be first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the top image first when you declare multiple background images.

I find this article great for explaining the stacking order of background images: http://css-tricks.com/stacking-order-of-multiple-backgrounds/

Hope this helps!

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/bX2k6/)**

```
.book_div:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
    background-image: url(./top_image.png), url(./bottom_image.svg);
}
```

Comment: Great! Was able to get it to work. But now I need to find out how to position the check mark if possible. Also, is there any way to keep the bg-image from unhovered state constant throughout hover instead of having to redefine it?